# How can insert code in createTextNode

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

Is there a way to insert HTML tag in 'createTextNod' or what else can I do

```
$.each(JSON.parse(results), function(i, field){
            for(var i = 1; i < JSON.parse(results).length; i++) {
                var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                var textNode = document.createTextNode(field.fname + ' ' + field.lname + ((field.status == 1) ? '<span class="userChatNameOnline">online</span>' : ''));
                newLi.appendChild(textNode);
                var ul = document.getElementById('ulUsers');
                ul.insertBefore(newLi, ul.childNodes[0]); 
            }
        })
```

Comment: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Just to make certain.  You aren't asking how to append an html node to a text node, with the desire that it renders as normal, rather than text ....... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues

The following part of OP code is pretty awful:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(results), function(i, field){
            for(var i = 1; i < JSON.parse(results).length; i++) {...
```

`$.each()` iterates through for each `field` in JSON which is OK. *But* you use *another* loop which is totally unnecessary since `$.each()` and `for` loop both iterate through arrays. Each of these loops is calling `JSON.parse()` on each iteration. Although no matter how bad this is, you'll probably never notice any lag unless you handle large amounts of data.

### References

The following are links to what was used:

**[Template Literals](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-template-strings-in-depth)**

**[.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)**

#### Demo

```js
var results = `[{"first":"Kaiser","last":"Soze","status":"1"},{"first":"Darth","last":"Vader","status":"0"},{"first":"Boba","last":"Fett","status":"0"},{"first":"Grim","last":"Reaper","status":"1"},{"first":"zer0","last":"0ne","status":"1"}]`;

var JSONData = JSON.parse(results);

var list = document.getElementById('users');

$.each(JSONData, function(idx, field) {
  var name = `[${idx}]: ${field.first} ${field.last}`;
  var status = `<b class='status' data-status='${field.status}'>${field.status === "1" ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</b>`;
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li class='userData'>${name}&nbsp;&nbsp;${status}</li>`);
});
```

```css
#users {
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none
}

.userData {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
}

.status {
  float: right
}

[data-status='1'] {
  color: green
}

[data-status='0'] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul id='users'></ul>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`createTextNode` is for creating a TextNode specifically, not inserting HTML. For the latter you can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [insertAdjecentHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Thank you newLi.innerHTML = field.fname + ' ' + field.lname + ((field.status == 1) ? '<span class="userChatNameOnline">online</span>' : ''); did the trick

Answer (score 1):

since you're using jQuery, you probably want to just create your nodes using `$()` and `.html()`:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(results), function(i, field){
    var ul = $('#ulUsers');
    for (var i = 1; i < JSON.parse(results).length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li></li>').html('<span>' + ... + '</span>');
        ul.before(li);
    }
}
```

If you want to streamline it, I suggest appending to a DocumentFragment and then appending the fragment's contents to `#ulUsers` in one go. jQuery encapsulates this if you pass an array of elements to be apppended (of course, if you want to give the dynamic effect of seeing the list grow as elements are added to the list, you wouldn't (need to) do this):

```
$.each(JSON.parse(results), function(i, field){
    var ul = $('#ulUsers');
    var li_array = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < JSON.parse(results).length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li></li>').html('<span>' + ... + '</span>');
        li_array.push(li);
    }
    ul.before(li_array);
}
```